# Can we able to use MS sql database in piwik ?

Tags: matomo

Can we able to use MS SQL in piwik? Tried to import MS SQL database to MYSQL but it shows version error. thanks

Comment: What does the piwik documentation say?

Comment: Also your question is unclear: what database did you try to import? Piwik generates its own table structure. And what "version error"?

Comment: The below error is what iam getting now while importing it to MYSQL : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: The MS SQL looks like different to MYSQL.The two database syntax are different.

Comment: I can only repeat my question: what database are you trying to import? I suggest you post (an initial bit of) your sql so that we get an impression what the issue might be. The error you post indicates that you try to load something _empty_ into MySql... So it might also be of interest _how_ you try to import.

Comment: Microsoft SQL database, /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[BandWidthAdmin5888]    Script Date: 05/07/2014 10:39:38 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BandWidthAdmin5888](
 [Stream-Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [CurrentState] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [Process] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
 [DateTime] [smalldatetime] NULL,
 [IPaddress] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [UploadedBytes] [nvarchar](max) NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: Sorry, that is hard to read... Please always add such information to the original question, since it is additional information. Do not post it as a comment. You can use the `edit` button you see right below the question for that. At first glance I would say: sorry, but that is not valid sql...

Comment: I still do not understand what you are trying to do. You want to use piwik with mssql? Then why an import into mysql? Also note that the piwik documentation clearly states that currently piwik only supports mysql. If however you want to use piwik with mysql, then how does mssql come into play?

Comment: I want to use piwik with Microsoft SQL

Comment: As said: take a look into the documentation and into the piwik forums, MS-SQL is _not_ supported due to its dialect of the sql standard.

Answer (score 1):

```
No this will not work for Piwik. Right now Piwik only supports MySQL.
```

check this link:
http://forum.piwik.org/read.php?2,102221